# How to structure angular services?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and having issues with properly setting up services that load and expose data.

The issue is that before I load data, I FIRST need a key to be loaded from the current user so that the proper user's data is loaded from the other services.

So right now, AuthService watches for a login and then loads a userData object.  Once userData is loaded, AuthService $emits 'login' which all of the other services watch for via $on and then load their own data.

This works and all of the services load their data, but I am having issues now with controllers initializing properly since they sometimes load before the data services (like on a page refresh).  It seems that passing empty objects initially from controllers to some 3rd party plugins (like ui-grid) causes issues.  Should I set up resolves in ui-router to prevent state change before data comes in from services?  That doesn't seem like since it will hang on larger datasets…

Any help would be much appreciated…

TLDR i need a controller to wait for a service (dataService) to load which needs for wait for another service (userDataService) to load.

Comment: could you show use your some of code..as how you are doing that currently? I'd give one of the suggestions to use `resolve` of state

Comment: I actually found that my issue was I was initializing ui-grid with an empty object instead of an empty array :)